# Unable to getActiveUser in googles apps script despite adding scopes to the manifest file

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to call getEmail() from my script but consistently get the following error.  The script is triggered by a form submission which otherwise runs successfully:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getEffectiveUser. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
    at onFormSubmit(Code:55:24)
```

The line of code in question is:

```
let activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail ;
```

This is what I have in my manifest file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For some users there can be as google describes in their documentation a complex set of protocols that prevent you from accessing the users email.  So even if you have the correct scopes, on some users it simply will not work and there is no workaround.

Comment: I am actually testing using my own email but I take your point.

Comment: I am trying this on with my own personal Gmail account and Google Sheets and it is not working when I edit my own Google Sheet. Does that seem right?

`function setUserEmail(x) {
  if(x != ""){
    return  Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  }
}`